# MySQL: shift all dates forward so max date = now

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1093

Here is a sample of my `results` MySQL table:

[image]

I would like to shift forward all dates for a specific user by the same interval, so that the highest date for that user is the current timestamp.  I know how to get the interval in days:

```
/* result is 823 */
SELECT DATEDIFF(
   CURDATE(),
   (SELECT MAX(r.`LastReviewed`) 
    FROM `results` r
     WHERE r.`UserID` = 1)
)
```

But I don't know how to use that information in the greater query that would shift dates forward.  I've tried:

```
UPDATE `results` r
SET r.`LastReviewed` = 
        r.`LastReviewed` + 
        INTERVAL (
            SELECT DATEDIFF(
               CURDATE(),
               (SELECT MAX(r.`LastReviewed`) 
                FROM `results` r
                 WHERE r.`UserID` = 1)
            )
        ) DAY
WHERE r.`UserID` = 1
```

But this errors with:

> Error Code 1093: You can't specify target table 'r' for update in FROM clause

2nd problem is that even if it worked, it runs the risk of shifting the max record into the future if it occurs near the end of the day (11:59 pm). I'd like the new max to be the current datetime

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e5ebb/2)

Comment: you can't do it one query. you need the subquery to get the max value, but that means you're reading from a table you're trying to update. do it in two: fetch the max, then use that for a separate update.

Comment: @MarcB Hi Marc. I'm having trouble with the logic of it. The subquery is not dependent on the superquery so why would it matter? Isn't the subquery executed and completed first?

Comment: yes, it is. you have have `update results ... (select ... from results)`. so you're selecting from a table you're targeting for an update. mysql simply does not allow this. the only permissible workaround is to use a `join` instead of a subquery. but since you need to do aggregate functions, that won't work too well.

Comment: @MarcB Ok. What do you think about the 2nd part of my problem (last sentence in OP). I can get the DATEDIFF in days but it will cause some events to be pushed into the future

Comment: the logic is sound enough. `diff = now() - max(timefield)`, then `update foo set timefield=timefield+diff where id <> record_with_max_field` (just pseudo-code, won't work).

Comment: @MarcB You misunderstand me (or I, you). Suppose `max(timefield)` is yesterday at 11:59pm.  When I do `timefield += diff`, the new value will be today at 11:59pm.  That's into the future. I'd like the diff to be such that the new value is right now; there must be no `timefield > current_datetime`

Comment: engine may just be getting confused about r alias as it's used twice and trying to coorlate the tables.  Change the r alias on inner query to Z or something else `(SELECT MAX(Z.LastReviewed) FROM results Z WHERE Z.UserID = 1)` or use a cross join since you know you only what the difference between the max and the current date..

Comment: then don't use datediff. it only does DATES. timediff will handles time as well. but note that it has a max of +/- 838 hours for the representable interval. if you want to handle arbitrary dates, then convert to/from unixtimestamps, which are simple integers and have date AND time in them.

Comment: @xQbert I thought so too but that's not it; using a different alias doesn't change the error (error still refers to table `r`).  @MarkB ok thank you

Comment: Could the functions TIMEDIFF() or UNIX_TIMESTAMP() (if the time is within range of a Unix timestamp) be used to calculate the time difference, and then add it back to the date?

Comment: @user6368519 Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with two consecutive statements.

```
SELECT @offset := DATEDIFF(
   CURDATE(),
   (SELECT MAX(LastReviewed) 
    FROM results
     WHERE UserID = 1)
);
UPDATE results
   SET LastReviewed = LastReviewed + INTERVAL @offset DAY
 WHERE UserID = 1;
```

**Edit**  Oh, you have to do it for everybody, eh? Let's use a temporary table. (These guys disappear when you're done with them.)

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE offsets
 SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),MAX(LastReviewed)) offset,
        UserId  
   FROM results
  GROUP BY UserId;

 UPDATE results
   JOIN offsets ON results.UserId = offsets.UserId
    SET results.LastReviewed = results.LastReviewed + INTERVAL offsets.offset DAY;
```

The temp table contains one row for each user. It overcomes the restriction that you can't do a summary query (`MAX()` in your case) in an update statement that updates the table.

Comment: Thanks Ollie. In the 2nd query, will the DB know which table `r` refers to?

Comment: Ooops, typo. The second query needs the  table name.

Comment: +1 I do pretty much the same thing when creating test data in our developers' sandbox databases. It must be done in two steps.

Comment: @BillKarwin @OllieJones; can the `@offset` be overwritten safely?  Meaning I need to loop through a list of users and shift their timestamps forward. So if I have 20 users I would have 40 consecutive queries and will be assigning a new value to `@offset` 20 times.  Any problem with that?

Comment: Nope, no problem with that.